# React test for prop method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have the following:

```
...
type RepairsProps = {
  repairs: Property[]
  repairsPropertyLoad(getToken: string | (() => Promise<string>)): Promise<void>
}

const Repairs: React.FC<RepairsProps> = ({repairs, repairsPropertyLoad}) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation()
  const [isARepair, setRepair] = useState(true)
  const handleOnClick = () => { 
    setRepair(false)
    repairsPropertyLoad('token')
  }
...
```

and a test that simulates the click event for handleOnClick like so:

```
  it('should render the Repairs component when isARepair is false after the repairsButton has been clicked', () => {
    fireEvent.click(repairsButton)
    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
```

how can I test that also `repairsPropertyLoad` has been called?

Comment: How do you pass repairsPropertyLoad to the component?

Comment: It's a connected component

Comment: Yes I can see that, but how do you declare that. E.g. you could check, if the store updates correctly or by overriding the function with a jest mock function.

Answer (score 0):

So where you have

```
render(< Repairs />);
```

you just need to pass spy:

```
const repairsPropertyLoad = jest.fn();
render(< Repairs />);
```

and later you will be able to test if that's called:

```
expect(repairsPropertyLoad).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

If you put `repairsPropertyLoad` outside `it()`(say on `describe()` level) you need to [clear mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestclearallmocks) on each run:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.clearAllMocks();
});
```

otherwise your `expect(...).toHaveBeenCalled()` will be affected by any previous `it()` runs.

Comment: repairsPropertyLoad is only called on click hence `fireEvent.click(repairsButton)`

Comment: so call `expect(repairsPropertyLoad).toHaveBeenCalled();` after `fireEvent.click(repairsButton)`